# How to Read XML Multi Tag in VB.Net

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

My `Xml` File is look like

```
  <MainTitle>
      <Text>BRICK kfhy;</Text>
      <Select>0</Select>

   <ContentObject> 
      <TextContent>  True </TextContent>
      <ImageContent> False </ImageContent>
    </ContentObject>

    <FONTS>
       <Name>4;Anglican;1;AndyMacarthurSH;5;Tsunami 9.0</Name> 
       <Size> 48 </Size>
       <Color> Color.Red </Color>
      <Multiple> True </Multiple>
     </FONTS>

   </MainTitle>
```

My Code:

```
   Dim _xdoc As New XDocument()
  _xdoc = XDocument.Load(_rdFl$)
   Dim GetValues = (From T In _xdoc...<MainTitle> _
                         Select Text = T.<Text>.Value,
                         TextContent = T.<TextContent>.Value,
                            FontName = T.<FontName.Value,
                               Color = T.<Color.Value)
```

Here I can read Text values but could not read **Font,Contentobject** values, I can understand that loop return the MAINTITLE sub nodes but how to get `ContentObject` with `Fonts` values here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim GetValues = (From T In _xdoc...<MainTitle> _
     Select Text = T.<Text>.Value,
     TextContent = T...<ContentObject>.<TextContent>.Value,
        FontName = T...<FONTS>.<FontName.Value,
           Color = T...<FONTS>.<Color.Value)
```

this code is worked fine, i can read values with in the multi tag xml